# Ionic v2 Put Image Over Image Responsively

Tags: html, css, image, ionic-framework

here is my codes below.How can i do my code responsive and well designed? I should not use "left" to position cover. I need the images over the other image suitable. 
Thanks

```
<ion-grid>
   <ion-row >
      <ion-col width-10>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col width-25>
      <div style="position: relative;display: inline-block;">
    <img class="wardrobe" src="{{gardirop}}" />


         <img class="cover_1" src="{{gardirop_cover_1}}" />


         <img class="cover_2" src="{{gardirop_cover_2}}" />

   </div>

      </ion-col>
       </ion-row></ion-grid>
```

.scss

```
.wardrobe {
z-index: 1;
position: relative;

}
.cover_1 {
z-index: 10;
position: absolute;
top:0px;
max-height: 450px;

}

.cover_2 {
z-index: 20;
position: absolute;
top:0px;
left:120px;
max-height: 450px;
display: inline-block;
}
```